# get cache name programmatically

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

In my application i  am using ehcache second level cache.in that application i remove the ehcache after add some data to db.here i send my ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="100000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="10"
        timeToLiveSeconds="10"
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        />
<cache 
name="com.model.Customer"
maxElementsInMemory="100000"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="10"
timeToLiveSeconds="10"
overflowToDisk="false" 
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
/>
<cache
name="com.model.Friend"
maxElementsInMemory="100000"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="10"
timeToLiveSeconds="10"
overflowToDisk="false" 
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
/>
</ehcache>
```

now i want remove cahche using this code

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
Cache cache = manager.getCache();
cache.removeAll();
```

so i need the cache name.so how will get my cache name?please help me any one
yes cache is configured correctly. and this is my java code for insert the data

```
Transaction trns = null;
Session session = HibernateUtil.getFirstFactory().openSession();
try 
{
 Customer cus=new Customer();
 cus.setName(name);
 cus.setMobile(Long.parseLong(mno));
 trns = session.beginTransaction();
 Query query=  session.createQuery("from Customer where name=? or mobile=?");  
 query.setParameter(0, cus.getName());
 query.setParameter(1, cus.getMobile());
 cus=(Customer)query.uniqueResult();
 if(cus==null)
 {
  cus=new Customer(name,Long.parseLong(mno),f);
  session.save(cus);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
 } 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
 if(trns != null){
 trns.rollback();
}
e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
  CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
  String[] names = manager.getCacheNames();
  System.out.println("length="+names.length);//here the output is length=0
  for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)//so the control terminate the loop so the cache does   not remove anything
  {
System.out.println("name="+names[i]);
    Cache cache = manager.getCache(names[i]);
    cache.removeAll();
  }
  session.flush();
  session.close();
}
```

this is my customer class

```
 private Long cid;
private String name;
private Long mobile;
private Set<Friend> friends = new HashSet<Friend>(0);



public Customer(String name, Long mobile,Set<Friend> friends) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.friends=friends;
}

public Customer() {}

public Long getCid() {
    return cid;
}
public void setCid(Long cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Long getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(Long mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public Set<Friend> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

public void setFriends(Set<Friend> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}
```

and this is my Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.model.Customer" table="customer">
<cache usage="read-write"/>

    <id column="cid" name="cid" type="java.lang.Long"  >
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
        <property name="name"  />
        <property name="mobile" index="msisdn"/>

    <!--  <set name="cards" table="t_customer_card" cascade="all">
        <key column="code" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-many class="com.asta.model.Card" column="cid" unique="true" />
    </set>  -->
      <set name="friends" table="customer_friends" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="cid" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-many class="com.model.Friend" column="fid" unique="true" />
    </set>      
</class>

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

i don't know where did i mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache name should be exactly as you have declared it in the xml file, e.g.: `com.model.Customer`.

You can always call `CacheManager.getCacheNames()` to get the complete list.

Comment: thank for reply. CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
String[] names = manager.getCacheNames();
System.out.println("length="+names.length);i'm using this code but the output is length=0.so it didn't get any cache name

Comment: Have you managed to crack it finally (as you have accepted my answer)? Or does your comment still apply?

Comment: please send me the full code for how to get cache name.i'm using the above code.but it doesn't display any cache name.

Comment: I have tested this code on my local instance and found `manager.getCacheNames()` working and returning relevant array of cache names; it would be surprising otherwise. Are you sure your cache is configured correctly?

Comment: yes in my knowledge configure correctly i edit my code please refer it

Comment: sorry i did small mistake.now i cleared that mistake and i got the cache name.but i have another one doubt.in my project add the customer with friends.so i write two methods one for addcustomer another for addfrnd.insert the data is no prblem.my problem is first i display the friendlist for particular cusotmer using cache it display the list then i add the one friend to db then again i call the displayfrnd method i displays only the old value.latest added value is not display.bcoz the cache wat nor updated.how will i auto refresh the cache.this is my requirement please help me.

Comment: You need to create a separate post for this problem. This is how this site works.